# Not able to group data of similar type having a relation(in this case nearby friends) in a file from a large data of names of friends

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, file-io, file-handling

## I have two seperate text files of friends and people.

First I dealt with the people data

```
friends = input("enter name of your three friends with commas and no spaces please").split(',')

people = open('people.txt', 'r')
people_nearby = [line.strip()for line in people.readline()]
 people.close()
```

I then tried to create an intersection of sets of people and friends to find the common.

```
people_nearby_set = set(people_nearby)
friends_nearby_set = set(friends)
common_set = friends_nearby_set.intersection(people_nearby_set)
nearby_friends = open('nearby friends.txt', 'w')
for friend in common_set:
    print(f'{friend} is nearby you.Meet him or her!')
    nearby_friends.write(f'{friend}')
    nearby_friends.close()
```

At the end I have tried to group the similar data using iterations.

When I try to run the program, it returns with `process finished with exit code 0` but it's not executed and the file of friends does not contain grouped data of nearby friends.

Comment: Hi and welcome to S.O.! Could you please extend your post with an actual question?

Comment: Thank you @DavidTóth . The question goes like this-Write a python program that reads data from a friends file(text file) and in a list of three friends each time checks whether the friend is nearby.Also put the nearby friends in a separate nearby_friends.txt(text file)

Comment: This looks more like something you would like to achieve, not an actual question.. Still, the python code you posted should yield something similar.. For a question maybe you could post the output of the program, and next to it the output you expected from it.

Comment: Actually I am not getting any output.The program return """process finished with exit code 0""" but the program is not executed and the file of friends does not contain grouped data of nearby friends.

Comment: I edited your question with that information. Might be a start.

Comment: Thanks for editing.It is working now.

Comment: Could you please post an answer on how you solved your problem? that would help others looking at this questions! Thanks in advance! :)